# Unable to add start and end time to my YouTube downloader app Project using ytdl library

Tags: node.js, express, youtube, project, ytdl

I am working on creating an application that can be used to download videos on YouTube.
From my research, All available applications doesn't allow you to specify the start time and the end time of the video duration you wish to download instead of the full videos as usual.

So I embarked on using NodeJs and a library called ytdl-core.

Below is my code so far, my challenge is I can't still implement the start and end time for the app to download. Am only able to download the full application. Is there a way out?

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Server Works !!! At port 4000');
});
app.get('/download', (req,res) => {
var URL = req.query.URL;
res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="video.mp4"');
ytdl(URL, {
    format: 'mp4'
    }).pipe(res);
});
```

Frontend

```
var convertBtn = document.querySelector('.convert-button');
var URLinput = document.querySelector('.URL-input');
var start= document.querySelector('.startValue');
var end= document.querySelector('.endValue');

convertBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(`URL: ${URLinput.value}`);
    sendURL(URLinput.value);
});
function sendURL(URL) {
    window.location.href = `http://localhost:4000/download?URL=${URL}?startTime=${start}?endTime=${end}`;
}
```

I got the URL submitted by the user and passed via a query and used the package to download the video from YouTube.

```
app.get('/download', (req,res) => {
var URL = req.query.URL;
var startTime = req.query.startTime;
var endTime =  req.query.startTime;

res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="video.mp4"');
ytdl(URL, {
    format: 'mp4'
    }).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Not implemented. You can, of course, download the whole file and pass the output to ffmpeg (not directly piping to res)

Comment: There is a `range` option, but works with bytes, not seconds. You have to do the conversion yourself

Comment: Can you throw more light on that with a code snippet

Comment: A snippet, no… Dozens of lines. Temp files etc. If you try, I can assist  you